# how to model this context that has custom form fields

Tags: database-design

Im studying about db and Im doing some modeling exercises. But in one Im not able to find a solution.

**Context**

There is a entity "Conference" that can have 1 ore more registration types. For each registration type there are 2 mandatory fields: name and email.

But then, where I have the doubt is that, beside these 2 mandatory fields, a conference can be created with different registration types and each registration type can have custom fields, for example besides name and email the conference creator can also collect phone or something. These custom fields can be: checkbox, input, select, textarea, date and upload file. And the conference creator can select each field as mandatory or not.

**Doubt**

Im trying to find a solution for this modeling but without success. Do you know how this can be modeled?

In this scenario I identify the entities: conference, registration type and  form, and they are related like:

```
1 to many relationship from Conference To Registration type (non-identifying)
1 to many relationship from RegistrationType to Form  (non-identifying)
```

So:

```
Conference: ConferenceID, Name, etc
RegistrationType: RegistrationTypeID, Name, Description, capacity, etc, ConferenceConferenceID
Form: idForm, RegistrationTypeRegistrationTypeID
```

But then do you know how the custom fields part can be designed?

Comment: When you say "doubt" do you mean "question"?

Answer (score 0):

The case of registration types looks like a classic case of classes and subclasses or, if you prefer, types and subtypes.  This king of thing comes up all the time, in practice. But it is often skipped over in data modeling tutorials.

Object modelers use the inheritance facilities built into the object model to handle this very easily.  The subclasses just extend the classes.

ER modelers can picture this in an ERD using a figure for "generalization and specialization".  But ER modeling doesn't tell you how to build the tables.

Check out these tags.

[single-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/single-table-inheritance)
[class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance)
[shared-primary-key](/questions/tagged/shared-primary-key)

Look at the questions grouped under the tags, and the info tab.  They will show you how to build your tables.  You have to pick between single table and class table.  Single table is probably good enough for your needs.